# Using Openmaptiles Tileshrink tool with boundsfilter and negative latitude gives an error

Tags: openmaptiles

I am using the Openmaptiles tool Tileshrink-gl in Docker to downsize a mbtiles map file. While It's working ok with positive latitude and longitude values, I get an error while using a negative latitude value, e.g.:

`docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/data tileshrink-gl maps/osm-2019-10-14-v3.10-south-america_colombia.mbtiles maps/curacao_lvl_14.mbtiles --bounds -68.601379,11.946632,-69.223480,12.425848 --maxzoom 14 -O -s maps/style_nothing.json`

The error output is:
`'--bounds' expects a value`

Answer (score 0):

TIP: Add quotes around the numbers in bounds.

UPDATE: `--bounds="-68.601379,11.946632,-69.223480,12.425848`"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please elaborate on where to put the quotes? I already tried the following variants:  `"-68.601379,11.946632,-69.223480,12.425848"` `'-68.601379,11.946632,-69.223480,12.425848'` `'-68.601379','11.946632','-69.223480','12.425848'`  `"-68.601379","11.946632","-69.223480","12.425848"` 
The result is still: ` '--bounds' expects a value`